# switchover in postgres9.0

Tags: postgresql

I already setup Primary(master) and Secondery(standby) Servers.
Now, I need to do switchover. that means standby should be master and master should be standby.

how to perform switchover in Postgres 9?

Answer (score 1):

check your recovery.conf file. you should show a trigger file.

```
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'host=127.0.0.1 port=5850 user=postgres'
trigger_file = '/home/pgdba/data2/finish.replication'
```

Create the trigger file (it can be empty) to trigger the switchover.